# getting at least 1 of 2 zero or more sets with a regular expression

Tags: regex

How would I write a regular expression that allows for zero or more of one group, and zero or more of another group, but at least one of the two groups has to exist?

Specifically, I want to get a spreadsheet like reference, so it should get A1:B5 (for a whole region), A:A (for a whole column), or 5:5 (for a whole row).

I first tried

```
[A-Za-z]*[\d]*:[A-Za-z]*[\d]*
```

but this wouldn't be sufficient because then simply typing : or B6: would also satisfy that criteria.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Something like: `^(?:([a-zA-Z]+\d+:[a-zA-Z]+\d+)|\d+:\d+|[a-zA-Z]+:[a-zA-Z]+)$`? ([example](http://regexr.com?30ns8))

Comment: Brad, great solution, would love to give you credit for this, but being that it's a comment, I can't. You should repost it as a real answer.

Comment: DigitalRoss has basically what I had in their edit (except the lowercase variety), you can give them the points. ;-)

Comment: Brad, can you explain what the purpose of the first question mark + colon is? It seems superfluous to me.

Comment: Non-capturing group. Just makes it so it needs to match, but doesn't necessarily need to return a result back.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with grouping...

```
/((how)|(now))+/
```

If you want to match a range but not a cell reference, you could just enumerate the ways to do that:

```
([A-Z]:[A-Z])|(\d+:\d+)|([A-Z]\d+:[A-Z]\d+)
```

Comment: This is nice, but not quite perfect, as it also captures the first part of something like A:B20, which is invalid.

Comment: Adjusted your approach to ^([A-Z]:[A-Z])$|^(\d+:\d+)$|^([A-Z]\d+:[A-Z]\d+)$ to avoid that problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be an explicit alternation:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z]+|\d+|[a-zA-Z]+\d+):(?:[a-zA-Z]+|\d+|[a-zA-Z]+\d+)
```

If your engine supports lookbehind, however, you could use that:

```
(?>[a-zA-Z]*\d*(?<=.)):(?>[a-zA-Z]*\d*)(?<=.))
```

This says "zero or more letters, followed by zero or more numbers, which must end in at least one character (.).  That guarantees it won't be empty.  The atomic grouping `(?>...)` means that the lookbehind `(?<=.)` can't match whatever came before that point.